# Establishing connection to database with wrong password in JAVA will count incorrect attempt

Tags: java

While establishing connection to database in Java we pass sever ip, username and password. In case my password is wrong then will it count as incorrect attempt or not ?. Since after n attempt my account will get locked and i need to handle this.Thanks.

Comment: Try to create a user-defined exception.